# NodeJs Express - Passing request parameter to passport authenticate

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a problem understanding nodejs syntax. I am trying to customize error messages of the passport and I am following this code:

```
router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, function(err, user, info) {
        //do some stuff here

        //if error, return some stuff
        res.json({...}) 

    })(req, res, next)
}
```

But in the syntax in the tutorial I am following, the router.route was made in this way:

```
router.route('/')
    .get(passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}, (err, user, info) => {
        //res cannot be found here
        res.json({...}) 

    }), UsersController.index);
```

Since I had this type of syntax where it involves the passport middleware and a controller, the **res.json()** becomes undefined..how do I pass the **res, req and next** parameters in this syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so *in general* I would not customize the error message in the authenticate callback like you want to do.  First, you'll be repeating yourself on each authenticate call if you do, and second it's just not the concern of that middleware.

I tend to centralize error handling and messaging, though, which is a longer discussion.

If you really want to do this, then you need to make sure `req, res, next` are in scope, like so:

```
app.route('/login')
   .get(function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
      if (err) { 
         err.message = 'Incorrect username or password';
         return next(err); 
      }
      if (!user) { return res.redirect('/login'); }
      req.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) { return next(err); }
        return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
      });
    })(req, res, next);
});
```

Ok, as for centralizing error handling, the approach I usually take is to create custom error classes that I can instantiate as needed and then handle in error-handling middleware.  That can be applied as easily to authentication as to anything else, and you can build them incrementally as the project grows so it's not too hard.  For example, starting with a custom FailedLoginError, I might do something like this (in ES6 syntax, it's no harder in older JS syntax):

```
// ./lib/errors/failed-login-error.js
class FailedLoginError extends Error {
  // You could set the message here if you wanted rather than letting the calling code set it
  constructor(error, userMessage) {
    super(error.message);
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
    this.previousError = error;
    this.statusCode = 401;
    this.userMessage = userMessage || 'You provided an incorrect username or password'; 
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
  }
}
```

Then I would create a custom middleware that wraps the Passport setup so that I don't have to remember to use that every time.

```
// ./lib/middleware/authenticate.js
// Similar to the example above, we have an error that has a 500 status
const ServerError = require('../errors/internal-server-error');
const FailedLoginError = require('../errors/failed-login-error');
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, (err, user, info) => {
    // an exception happened trying to do the login
    if (err) return next(new ServerError(err));
    // user was not correct.  Add more info to the error message if you want, like maybe the Username was incorrect or the Token was expired or whatever. 
    if (!user) return next(new FailedLoginError(err));
    // we get here and the user logged in right
    req.logIn(user, (e) => {
      if (e) return next(ServerError(e));
      return res.redirect('/users/' + user.username); // or whatever the right thing is here
    });
  });
});
```

Ok, so then with that setup, you can now setup some error handling middleware that takes advantage of your custom errors:

```
// ./lib/middleware/error-handler.js
module.exports = (err, req, res, next) {
  // normalize the possibly missing status and userMessages
  err.statusCode = err.statusCode || 500;
  err.userMessage = err.userMessage || 'Something went wrong.';

  // always log something; use something other than console.error if you like
  // note here we're logging the real error message. 
  console.error(`${req.method} ${req.url} - ${err.statusCode} - ${err.message}`);

  // next, give the user something you don't mind them seeing
  res.status(err.statusCode).send(err.userMessage);
};
```

Now to put all that together, your app code will simplify to something like this:

```
const errorHandler = require('./lib/middleware/error-handler');
const authenticate = require('./lib/middleware/authenticate');
// other requires as needed.

app.use(errorHandler);

app.route('/login')
   .all(authenticate)
   .get((req, res, next) => {
     // whatever you want to do here, it's already got a user and so on.  
   });
```

I put together a library a while ago that uses this pattern and creates a bunch of generic HTTP error classes.  It's probably due for an update, but might give you some inspiration.  https://github.com/pvencill/praeter

Comment: centralizing error handling and messaging for me sounds like the best solution.. would you mind sharing how you would do it?

Comment: @muffin added info on centralizing error handling as requested.

Comment: Thank you, this is well implemented and explained as well